# How to kill locking query from "show processlist" in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I a have task to monitor queries on server and kill the queries which are locking other queries which I am doing from PHP code. 
I want to know if this is possible and how this can be done.

I have  searched existing questions on this topic but there was not any matching situation.

I am using `show processlist` to get list of queries.

I have checked the mysql site and found that "state" can be,

> Locked - The query is locked by another query.

But how to get process id of the query which has locked this query, so later I can kill this query by this id.

Answer (score 0):

The `SHOW PROCESSLIST;`  and `SELECT * FROM information_schema.PROCESSLIST;` returns session's `id` number. You can use this value in KILL function, e.g. -

```
KILL CONNECTION 337;
```

[KILL Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/kill.html)

Also, you can try KILL QUERY statement. From the documentation: *KILL QUERY terminates the statement that the connection is currently executing, but leaves the connection itself intact.itself intact.*